# Autoconf AC_CHECK_SIZEOF always 0 on CentOS

Tags: c++, centos, autoconf

I use GNU Autoconf 2.63 on CentoOS 6.3 32-bit. In my configure script I check the sizes of some types, like:

```
AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(char)
AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(int)
AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(long)
```

, but the result is always `0` when running `./configure`:

```
checking size of char... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
```

The same configurations run fine on Mac OS X SL and Ubuntu though.

Any ideas why `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` returns `0` on CentOS?

Comment: Are you able to dig out the relevant parts of `config.log`? That would give us some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that it was a lib that I linked in that was missing, when I added the correct symbolic link to the lib the `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` returned the correct values.

Solution was found here:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-autoconf/2012-08/msg00009.html

Comment: To follow up here, `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` seems to fallback to zero when the build fails, rather than return an error.  I think this is the source of the confusion.